# Octet-stream data URI ignoring <a> 'download' attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, http-headers

I have a download button on my page that looks like this:

```
<a download="test.jpg" href="data:application/octet-stream;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZ...">Download</a>
```

The `href` attribute is populated by JavaScript, and on my test server it functions exactly as I'd expect it to: it prompts a 'Save As' dialogue box with the filename "test.jpg".

However, when I use the exact same code on a different, live server, the filename is dropped.

- In Chrome it saves as 'download', without a file extension
- In Firefox it saves as a seemingly random string, again without a file extension

Any ideas what could be causing this difference in behaviour across the two servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a security measure applies when saving off-site downloads. since the prototcols don't match (data vs http), it's considered a different site, and a default names gets applies. Use URL.createObjectURL instead of base64 to feed the download's href. you can get a [dataURL to Blob routine in my downlod.js library](https://github.com/rndme/download/blob/master/download.js#L87), then feed the Blob to createObjectURL().